I can't send an email to email accounts on this host via PHPMailer on Bluehost
I'm trying to send emails to an email account that was created on the website serviciodecorreo.es, however, from the PHP debug all seems to be OK but the message never arrives to the desired email account, here is the debug message:
I've been trying different codes but the problem persist, with this one at least the debug says it's OK but I don't know what to try anymore:
<?php
session_start();



use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;


require '/home/path/to/autoload.php';

require '/home/path/to/src/Exception.php';
require '/home/path/to/src/PHPMailer.php';
require '/home/path/to/src/SMTP.php';

// Instantiation and passing [ICODE]true[/ICODE] enables exceptions
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);



try {
// SMTP server config
$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                                       // Debug (0 para deshabilitar)
$mail->isSMTP();                                            // Uses SMTP
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
$mail->Host       = 'mail.domain.site';             // SMTP server host
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   // SMTP Authentication
$mail->Username   = 'user@domain.site';                   // SMTP user
$mail->Password   = 'password';                          // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
$mail->Port = 465;



// Sender and receiver
$mail->setFrom('sender@domain.com');  // Dirección y nombre del remitente
$mail->addAddress('receiver@domain.com');   // Añade un destinatario

/*
    // SSL options config
$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
    'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true,
        'cafile' => '/home/path/to/cacert.pem', 
    ),
);*/

// Email contents
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = 'Two Factor Authentication';
//$mail->Body    = strval($_SESSION['factor']);
//$mail->AltBody = strval($_SESSION['factor']);
$mail->Body    = 'Hello';
$mail->AltBody = 'Hello';

$mail->send();

} catch (Exception $e) {

}


Can you confirm that you have the necessary permissions to send email using the 'from' email address you have specified?  You can put anything you like in 'from', but if you don't have the right configuration and permissions set up, it will most likely be blocked by spam filters.

Also, you are using a try {...} with an empty catch {} block, which means you're explicitly ignoring any exceptions thrown by your code.  Instead, you might want to log those to see if that provides some insights.

As well as removing the pointless try/catch, please read the phpmailer troubleshooting guide (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting) and work through that to try and resolve any issues revealed by the logs etc. We don't know what is in your debug logs, because you didn't show us, so we don't know if it indicated any potential problems or not.

Also here's a good general guide to debugging email problems in PHP (and in general): https://stackoverflow.com/a/24644450/5947043 . Even if you can prove that the mailserver has accepted your message, there are still things that can go wrong

If sending is succeeding, that's where your script's involvement ends, but if it's not arriving, check your spam folder, and be sure that your from address can actually receive bounces. Also, don't disable certificate verification – if you're getting TLS failures, it's likely for a good reason, for example transparent redirection by your hosting provider.

SetFrom accepts two values. SetFrom('from_address','from_name') - I've noticed in the past that certain mail servers don't like the missing from_name. Try adding that and see if your recipient receives happiness. Just a thought. Happy hunting.
